# Is a React Native app with Bun runtime possible?

Tags: react-native, bun

Bun performance is great compared with Node.js.

It allows to run a React app. Is it also possible to run a React Native app with the Bun runtime?

Answer (score 3):

Just install Bun and run `bun run start` assuming you have the `start` script in [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) pointing to `react-native start`.

But I can't see the benefit of running React Native over Bun as Bun will not be compiled into native (run on device).

If you're looking for better performance running your jsbundle, just use [Hermes](https://github.com/facebook/hermes).

Comment: FYI performance is usually _worse_ with Hermes. The only thing Hermes improves is startup time. Other than that Hermes is [slower and less efficient](https://github.com/Kudo/react-native-js-benchmark) and is missing lots of features. It even does dangerous stuff like treating all `let` and `const` as `var` which _will_ cause subtle bugs and memory leaks if you don't transpile everything to var safely first. IMO it's not production ready despite Facebook declaring it the new default runtime for RN.

Comment: I think we can at least benefit from improved performance on tests and ESLint.